# React state has right value in render but not on component function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this problem where component correctly renders state but when I use state in a function, it still holds initial value.

In component render anyway, deviceInfo shows right infos.

```
const [deviceInfo, setDeviceInfo] = useState({id: null, info: null});
const subscribed = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    sub = subscriber.subscribe(device_info => { // subscriber of rxjs
        if (!subscribed.current) {
            subscribed.current = true;
            if (device_info.id && device_info.info) {
                setDeviceInfo({id: device_info.id, info: device_info.info}); // -> setDeviceInfo useState setter called
                oauth(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(device_info)));
            }
        }
    });
    if (deviceInfo.info) sub.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

when I use state in function it still has initial value `{ id: null, info: null }`

```
 const requestToken = async (device_auth_res) => {
    ... 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.status + ' ' + err.message);
        const type = err.response.body['error'];
        if (type === 'authorization_pending') {
            console.error('Authorization pending...')
        }
        if (type === 'expired_token') {
            console.error(err.response.body.error_description);
            await requestOauth(deviceInfo); // -> deviceInfo is { id: null, info: null }
        }
        if (type === 'auth_request_not_found') {
            console.error(err.response.body.error_description);
            await requestOauth(deviceInfo); // -> deviceInfo is { id: null, info: null }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the bottom function is called? it seems that it relies on a frozen context.

Comment: @MarioVernari it is called from an interval that periodically calls requestToken function

Comment: Is inside the effect ? If yes can you show the code. I may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a ref that always points to the latest state. This way, even if your function captures an old value of the ref, dereferencing the ref will always give you the current state.

```
const deviceInfoRef = useRef(deviceInfo);

useEffect(() => {
    deviceInfoRef.current = deviceInfo;
}, [deviceInfo]);

const requestToken = async (device_auth_res) => {
    // ... use deviceInfoRef.current instead of deviceInfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as bellow code:

```
const [deviceInfo, setDeviceInfo] = useState({ id: null, info: null });
const subscribed = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  let sub;
  sub = subscriber.subscribe((device_info) => {
    if (!subscribed.current) {
      subscribed.current = true;
      if (device_info.id && device_info.info) {
        setDeviceInfo({ id: device_info.id, info: device_info.info });
        oauth(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(device_info)));
      }
    }
  });
  if (deviceInfo.info) sub.unsubscribe();
}, []);

const requestToken = async (device_auth_res) => {
  // Use deviceInfo directly here
  try {
    // ...

    const type = err.response.body['error'];
    if (type === 'authorization_pending') {
      console.error('Authorization pending...');
    }
    if (type === 'expired_token') {
      console.error(err.response.body.error_description);
      if (deviceInfo.id && deviceInfo.info) {
        await requestOauth(deviceInfo);
      }
    }
    if (type === 'auth_request_not_found') {
      console.error(err.response.body.error_description);
      if (deviceInfo.id && deviceInfo.info) {
        await requestOauth(deviceInfo);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.status + ' ' + err.message);
  }
};
```

you can use the deviceInfo state variable directly within the requestToken function, but make sure to handle potential null values appropriately to avoid errors.

```
const [deviceInfo, setDeviceInfo] = useState({ id: null, info: null });
const subscribed = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const sub = subscriber.subscribe((device_info) => {
    if (!subscribed.current) {
      subscribed.current = true;
      if (device_info.id && device_info.info) {
        setDeviceInfo({ id: device_info.id, info: device_info.info });
        oauth(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(device_info)));
      }
    }
  });
  if (deviceInfo.info) sub.unsubscribe();
}, []);

const requestToken = async (device_auth_res) => {
  try {
    // Use deviceInfo directly here
    console.log('Inside requestToken:', deviceInfo); // Verify if it's updated

    // ... your code ...

    const type = err.response.body['error'];
    if (type === 'authorization_pending') {
      console.error('Authorization pending...')
    }
    if (type === 'expired_token' || type === 'auth_request_not_found') {
      console.error(err.response.body.error_description);
      if (deviceInfo.id && deviceInfo.info) {
        await requestOauth(deviceInfo);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.status + ' ' + err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: also using deviceInfo before try { } the result is the same -> { id: null, info: null} but in browser I can see deviceInfo correctly rendered

Comment: for the moment I resolved definind a variable inside my component where to hold the same device_info value and using that in component instead of state variable deviceInfo

Comment: I've add new update at the end of the last code. If you're seeing the correct value of deviceInfo in the browser, but it still shows as { id: null, info: null } when used within the try { } block or functions, there could be a few possible reasons for this behavior:

Timing Issue: The requestToken function or the code within the try { } block might be running before the setDeviceInfo function has had a chance to update the state. State updates in React are asynchronous, so you might be reading the state before it's updated.

Comment: Asynchronous Code: If requestToken or the code inside try { } block involves asynchronous operations (e.g., network requests), it's possible that the function is executing with the initial state value before the asynchronous operations are completed.

Closure Issue: As mentioned earlier, if you're capturing the state in a closure within your component, it might still hold the initial value.

Comment: To resolve these issues, make sure to handle asynchronous code properly and ensure that you're using the correct value of deviceInfo. Here's an example of how you might structure your code to address these concerns as above code . . . By logging the value of deviceInfo inside the requestToken function, you can verify whether it's being updated correctly. If it's still showing the initial value, you may need to adjust the timing or handle asynchronous operations appropriately to ensure you're working with the latest state.